# Will an gwt rpc call ALWAYS callback to either my onsuccess or onfail methods?

Tags: gwt, rpc

I have implemented the suggestion in this post and disable my button after the the first   click. [How to prevent DoubleSubmit in a GWT application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549049/how-to-prevent-doublesubmit-in-a-gwt-application)
What i want to know is with my button reenabled in both my fail and success methods will it always get reenabled. Also is there any place i can put some code that i always want executed when the server replies as opposed to duplicating it in both fail and success methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do think that either `onSuccess()` or `onFailure()` will be called every time.

As for having a place where you can put code that will always run when getting a response to the server you could just create an `AsyncCallback` which has the code in it's `onFailure()` and `onSuccess()` methods. Then you can just extend that `AsyncCallback` everytime you create an `AsyncCallback`.

```java
public MyAsyncCallback<T> extends AsyncCallback<T>(){

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable caught){
        //Do something
        onResponse()
        failed(caught);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(T result){
        //Do something
        onResponse()
        succeeded(result);
    }

    public void onResponse(){
        // Do something or nothing by default
    }

    public abstract void failed(Throwable caught);

    public abstract void succeeded(T result);

};
```

Whenever you want to create an `AsyncCallback` just use `MyAsyncCallback`:

```java
AsyncCallback callback = new MyAsyncCallback(){

    @Override
    public void failed(Throwable caught){
        //Do something
    }

    @Override
    public void succeeded(T result){
        //Do something
    }  

    // Optionally override onResponse() if needed
    @Override
    public void onResponse(){
        //Do something
    }

}
```

Comment: Problem with this approach is I need different behaviour depending on what button or action the user performed. Apologised I have mistook your answer.

Comment: Oh I guess I misunderstood. You could just add a method to your `AsyncCallback` such as `public void onResponse(){...}` and then call it from both `onSuccess()` and `onFailure()`.

Comment: @MayoMan I changed my implementation a bit to account for what you want. At least as far as I understand what you want to do.